# Carousel - Grid Spacing Issues (images getting crunched) - CSS - Using Unbounce (which lets you build websites)

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, unbounce

I'm having trouble getting this spacing down with my carousel.  The difficult part is I'm using an in browser service, Unbounce to build the website (for a client) so this is an html/css snippet I have drop into the wysiwyg website framework. The spacing I am trying to achieve is where it goes across half the page horizontally. I also attempted using a more mobile friendly image (square image), but I still got the same result.
Here is what it looks like:
[image: Crunched together carousel images]

Here is what it should look like (normal PNG image with no background):
[image: Intended image look]

Slider Element

```
  <div id="slider">

  <div class="testi-bx">
    <img src="" class="desk">
    <img src="" class="mob"> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="testi-bx">
    <img src="" class="desk">
    <img src="" class="mob">   
  </div>

   <div class="testi-bx">
     <img src="" class="desk">
     <img src="" class="mob"> 
  </div>
  
</div>

<script>
$('#slider').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 4000,
    dots:false,
  arrows:true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
    pauseOnHover: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots:false
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows:false,
        dots:true,

      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows:false,
        dots:true,
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
    // 1024
  ]  

}); 
</script>
```

Slider Stylesheet

```
<style>
   
.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
  
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
     
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}

.slick-dots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.slick-dots li {
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background-color:#E21836;
}

.slick-dots button {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    border: none;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: transparent;
    /*border: 1px solid #E2714E;*/
    margin: 0 2px;
}
  
  .slick-prev.slick-arrow {
    background-image: url("");
    content: "";
    color: transparent;
    height: 16px !important;
    width: 9px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 42px;
    top: 35%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 555;
  }
  
  
    .slick-next.slick-arrow {
      background-image: url("");
      content: "";
      color: transparent;
      height: 16px !important;
      width: 9px !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      font-size: 42px;
      top: 35%;
      right: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 556;
    }
  
  
  
/*.slick-prev::before {
    background-image: url("");
    content: "";
    color: transparent;
    height: 30px !important;
    width: 30px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 42px;
}
.slick-next::before {
    background-image: url("");
    content: "";
    color: transparent;
    height: 30px !important;
    width: 30px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 42px;
}*/

.slick-next, .slick-prev {
    width: 19px;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 0px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}

    
  .slick-slide img.desk {
    width: 890px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 00px;
    

  }
  
  .slick-slide img.mob {
    width: 290px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
   
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .slick-slide img.desk {

    display: none;
  }
  
  .slick-slide img.mob {

    display: block;
  }
    
    
    .slick-dots{margin-top: 25px;}
    
    .slick-prev.slick-arrow{bottom: 3.6em !important; left: 40% !important; top: auto;}
    .slick-next.slick-arrow{bottom: 3.6em !important; right: 40% !important; top: auto;}
    

}
  
</style>
```

Comment: Can you share the ```CSS``` included to give dimensions to the images?

Comment: Apologies! Just added the style sheet in.  Appreciate your help!